# how to compare specific number in a column and drive their respective relation in the other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a following columns in a table

```
TicketNumber    MachineNo.    Time
456                 11        10/02/2017 7:12
789                 13        10/02/2017 8:12
456                 22        10/02/2017 11:13
123                 11        10/02/2017 9:59
789                 24        10/02/2017 9:12
123                 22        10/02/17 11:59
```

the ticket numbers repeats for two or three times in the table and are first linked with machine no. having odd numbers (which are limited to 11,13) and then it will be linked to even numbers (limited to 22, 24) to get the following result.

```
TicketNumber    Machineno.   TimeIn             Machineno.   Timeout
456                 11       10/02/2017 7:12    22           10/02/2017 11:13
789                 13       10/02/2017 8:12    24           10/02/2017 9:12
123                 11       10/02/2017 9:59    22           110/02/17 11:59
```

Comment: You say " or three times" but your example doesn't show this or give any indication of what results are desired for that case

Comment: i have limited the machine no. to (11 or 13) and (22 or 24) so the "third time" will not be considered.

Comment: @GurV, thanks for editing.

Comment: @Mansoor - Do you want to get the result based on the earliest time and latest time per ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
INTO #tbl_Table FROM ( VALUES 
(456,11,'10/02/2017 7:12'),
(789,13,'10/02/2017 8:12'),
(456,22,'10/02/2017 11:13'),
(123,11,'10/02/2017 9:59'),
(789,24,'10/02/2017 9:12'),
(123,22,'10/02/17 11:59')
) as a (TicketNumber,MachineNo, DTime)
GO
SELECT * 
FROM #tbl_Table as t1
INNER JOIN #tbl_Table as t2
ON t1.TicketNumber = t2.TicketNumber
WHERE (t1.MachineNo = 11 or t1.MachineNo = 13)
AND t2.MachineNo != 11 and t2.MachineNo != 13
```

[image]

Comment: the ticket number will be changing and will not be specific as shown above.

Comment: You are kidding me. Try the code I've posted. It returns EXACTLY same result as in your example :-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a straight forward pivot.

```
SELECT ticketNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MachineNo IN (11,13) THEN machineno END) machineno_in,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MachineNo IN (11,13) THEN Time END) time_in,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MachineNo IN (22,24) THEN machineno END) machineno_out,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MachineNo IN (22,24) THEN Time END) time_out
FROM   YourTable
WHERE MachineNo IN (11,13,22,24)
GROUP  BY ticketNumber;
```

Comment: it worked. thank you!! in addition, i was trying to sort out the result in terms of timing. like how many ticket number were present in the time interval of 8am to 10am. so with the above table only one line will be a shown as result that is ticket number '789'.

Comment: hello martin..struggling to get the time restriction..could you provide your inputs?